# Cast<T> для набора элементов приводящихся к Т

Tags: c#

Есть класс, содержащий оператор приведения типа *int* к типу этого класса

```
class Item
{
    public int ID;

    public static implicit operator Item(int id)
    {
        return new Item { ID = id };
    }
}
```

Если написать так

```
int id = 1;
Item item = id;
```

то приведение типа срабатывает.

Теперь я хочу набор *int*-ов преобразовать в набор *Item*-ов, соответственно я делаю

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Item[] items = ids.Cast<Item>().ToArray();
```

и получаю

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in System.Core.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32'
>   to type 'Item'.

Замена *implicit* на *explicit* не помогла.

Как это решить наиболее изящно, и (главное) почему *Cast<T>* не срабатывает?

Comment: Потому что Cast не использует пользовательские операторы.

Comment: Используйте `ids.Select(x => (Item)x)`.
А не работает потому-что `Cast` не generic, и мы пытаемся скастить `object` в наш `T`, из-за этого и получаем ошибку (тоже самое при боксинге/анбоксинге).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Cast` не срабатывает, потому что, если открыть его исходник, мы увидим следующее:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

т.е. по сути это эквивалентно

```
int id = 1;
Item item = (Item)(object)id;
```

что, естественно, не срабатывает, т. к. `object` нельзя преобразовать в ваш тип, да и оператор для явного/неявного преобразования из `object` вообще запрещено создавать.

Для того, чтобы ваш оператор использовался, компилятор должен видеть его и генерировать вызов при компиляции:

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Item[] items = ids.Select(i => (Item)i).ToArray();
```

с уже скомпилированными сборками это не сработает.

PS:

Вы, конечно, можете попытаться написать свой метод для каста:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> MyCast<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> sourse)
    {
        foreach (TIn e in sourse) yield return (TOut)e;
    }
}
```

Но это не скомпилируется, т. к. нельзя произвольный тип `TIn` преобразовать в произвольный `TOut`.

Вы можете попытаться добавить ограничение на типы:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> MyCast<TIn, TOut>(
        this IEnumerable<TIn> sourse) where TOut : TIn
    {
        foreach (TIn e in sourse) yield return (TOut)e;
    }
}
```

и этот класс даже скомпилируется, но вы не сможете им воспользоваться:

```
Item[] items = ids.MyCast<int, Item>().ToArray();
```

потому что `Item` не является (наследником) `int`.

---

Ну и, конечно, если уж вам на столько сильно нужно решение этой задачи, что вы готовы воспользоваться рефлексией или динамической типизацией, то можно придумать какое-то такое решение, которое найдет метод по его сигнатуре, создаст и него делегат и закеширует его:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> MyCast<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> sourse)
    {
        var castMethod = CastImpl<TIn, TOut>.CastMethod;
        foreach (TIn e in sourse) yield return castMethod(e);
    }

    static class CastImpl<TIn, TOut>
    {
        public static readonly Func<TIn, TOut> CastMethod;

        static CastImpl()
        {
            var attr = MethodAttributes.Static
                     | MethodAttributes.Public
                     | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
                     | MethodAttributes.SpecialName;
            var names = new[] { "op_Implicit", "op_Explicit" };
            var method = typeof(TIn).GetMethods()
                .Concat(typeof(TOut).GetMethods())
                .Where(mi => mi.Attributes == attr
                    && names.Contains(mi.Name)
                    && mi.ReturnType == typeof(TOut)
                    && mi.GetParameters() is ParameterInfo[] pi
                    && pi.Length == 1
                    && pi[0].ParameterType == typeof(TIn))
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (method == null) throw new NotSupportedException(
                $"Cast {typeof(TIn)} => {typeof(TOut)} not supported!");
            CastMethod = (Func<TIn, TOut>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TIn, TOut>));
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда, конечно, это будет работать:

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Item[] items = ids.MyCast<int, Item>().ToArray();
```

То же самое с использованием `Expression` будет выглядеть короче, за счет того, что метод для конвертации будет найден автоматически:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> MyCast<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> sourse)
    {
        var castMethod = CastImpl<TIn, TOut>.CastMethod;
        foreach (TIn e in sourse) yield return castMethod(e);
    }

    static class CastImpl<TIn, TOut>
    {
        public static readonly Func<TIn, TOut> CastMethod;

        static CastImpl()
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn), "i");
            var body = Expression.Convert(param, typeof(TOut));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, new[] { param });
            CastMethod = (Func<TIn, TOut>)lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Причем этот метод получается даже более универсальным, в нем сработает и привычный каст (в отличие от предыдущего):

```
var cars = items.MyCast<Vehicle, Car>();
```

Comment: Но можно принять `TIn` за `dynamic`

Comment: Но это уже не будет статической типизацией. При желании можно вообще добавить в `MyCast` поиск (и кеширование) оператора для преобразования типа через рефлексию

Comment: _"если открыть его исходник"_ я честно открывал, но под конец рабочего дня, увидел `(TResult)obj` и не понял, чего ж ещё надо, проглядел что там `object obj` и совсем нет `TSource`. До _Select_ я догадался, но это не изящно, т.к. это в десятке мест надо, а делать extension на _IEnumerable<int>_ как-то не хочется.

Comment: Вместо `where TOut : TIn` можно по идее какое-нибудь `where TOut : IConvertible<TIn>` попробовать изобразить. Вообще надо будет поэксперементировать с IConvertible/IConverter подходами. Динамическое приведение - интересный способ, но да, надо кэшировать. А если компилированное выражение сотворить (и тоже кэшировать) - это будет предпочтительнее, чем брать делегат через рефлексию, или без разницы?

Comment: `IConvertible` будет не сильно лучше, чем просто `Select`, т. к. эту лямбду для конвертации вам все равно придется где-то написать. Да, можно ещё попробовать собрать вручную expression, скомпилировать его в лямбду и закешировать. Что будет быстрее - не знаю, надо проверять. Но если число конвертаций n в программе много, то накладные расходы на создание и кеширование в расчете на одну конвертацию, в любом случае, стремятся к нулю при n → ∞

Comment: @i-one, добавил вариант с `Expression`, думаю, он вам больше понравится

Comment: Спасибо! Жаль, что в C# нет поддержки ограничений на приводимость типа, наподобие `where TOut : (TOut)TIn`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var test = Array.ConvertAll(ids, (p => (Item)p));//Вариант 1
var test2 = ids.Select(p => (Item)p).ToArray();  //Вариант 2
```

Проверял на твоем же коде.

Абсолютно успешно срабатывают оба. Выбирай любой который тебе больше по душе.

Не забудь подключить неймспейс: using System.Linq

Comment: _"неймспейс: using System.Linq"_ - да куда ж он родимый денется, Cast из него же.