# ushort в char при использовании Enumerable.Cast получаю предупреждение и исключение

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Почему когда я пытаюсь сделать каст массива `ushort[]` к `char[]`, то решарпер мне выдает предупреждение о том что я делаю подозрительное приведение типов:

> Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both `ushort` and `char`.

Но, я даже уже посмотрел и диапазон значений

```
Debug.Assert(char.MaxValue == ushort.MaxValue);
Debug.Assert(char.MinValue == ushort.MinValue);
```

А так же если все же выполнить такой код, то естественно получим исключение:

> System.InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является
>   недопустимым..

Т.е. я так понимаю тут приведение происходит при помощи оператора `as`?

Ведь если я буду вручную циклом перебирать массив, и делать явное приведение, то все значения `ushort`，нормально запишутся как `char`.

Т.е. вот так все нормально:

```
dataChars[i] = (char)data[i]; // где data массив ushort
```

Как можно объяснить такое поведение метода расширения `Linq`？

Upd:

Саму проблему нашел, исключение происходит если сделать каст `uhsort` > `object` > `char`.

Но, если сделать вот так:

```
(((IConvertible)object)ushort).ToChar(null);
```

То все отрабатывает как надо, не знаю с чем это связано, ведь `object` не реализует этот интерфейс *(думаю дело в упаковке ссылки, а не самого объекта)* . Но мне все же не понятно, почему так происходит, и интересно узнать почему.

Метод теста для воспроизведения проблемы:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UShortToObjectToCharTest()
{
    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidCastException>(() =>
    {
        const ushort testUshort = 10;
        object testObject = testUshort;
        ushort testUshort2 = (ushort)testObject;
        char testChar = (char) testUshort2;
        char testChar2 = (char) testObject; // падает ровно здесь.
    });
}
```

Данный тест всегда будет успешно пройден.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919154/218063

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать конкретно на ваш вопрос, то всё дело в использовании неуниверсального интерфейса `IEnumerable` вместо `IEnumerable<T>`.

Как ты уже правильно заметил: исключение происходит при преобразовании `uhsort -> object -> char`. Поскольку в метод `Cast` передаётся интерфейс `IEnumerable`, то возвращать такое перечисление будет тип `object`. Для значимых типов - это автоматом означает упаковку. Но вот распаковка, как известно, всегда должна производится в тот же тип, который был упакован. Тут даже тест не нужен - это [основа упаковки/распаковки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Исправить это не получится. Компилятор не может знать заранее будет ли условный обобщённый тип `TInput` явно преобразовываться в тип `TResult`, поскольку ничего про них не знает.

И кстати, приведение происходят через (). Оператор as можно использовать только с ссылочными типами и он вообще не бросает исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что кастинг из боксовой переменной работает только тогда, когда тип упакованного значения и тип в который вы кастуете точно совпадают.

Аналогичные вопросы на EnSO: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5312731/312041), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309460/312041)

Больше инфы в [блоге Эрика Липперта](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/)