# Игнорирование explicit при конвертации в рантайме

Tags: c#

Есть два класса Contact и ContactTarget:

```
public class Contact
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string PhotoUriThumbnail { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }

}

public class ContactTarget
{

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string OptionalPhones { get; set; }


    public static explicit operator ContactTarget(Contact contact)
    {
        var _contact =  new ContactTarget();
        _contact.Name = contact.Name;
        _contact.Phone = contact.Number;
        _contact.OptionalPhones = Convert.ToBoolean(contact.Numbers) ? string.Join(";", contact.Numbers) : string.Empty;
        _contact.Photo = contact.PhotoUriThumbnail ?? string.Empty;

        return _contact;
    }

    public void Log()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
    }

}
```

Изначально задача состояла в том, чтобы конвертировать список экземпляров класса Contact в ContactTarget. И ее реализация выглядела таким образом:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new List<Contact>()
        {
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" }
        };

        var b = a.Select(i => (ContactTarget)i).ToList();

        b[0].Log();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Все работало, как надо. Но затем задача усложнилась тем, что целевые типы для преобразования могут быть разными. Для ее реализации я ввел функцию iConvert:

```
    static List<T> iConvert<T>(List<Contact> raw)
    {
        var res = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Count; i++)
        {
            var r = (T)raw[i];
            res.Add(r);
        }
        return res;
    }   

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new List<Contact>()
        {
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" }
        };

        // var b = a.Select(i => (Contacts)i).ToList();
        var b = iConvert<ContactTarget>(a);

        b[0].Log();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Сделав это я столкнулся с некоторой проблемой, которой решения я нигде не нашел. Заключается она в том, что компилятор считает (T) отдельным типом: при вызове `iConvert<ContactTarget>(a)` я получаю **ошибку компиляции** на строке `var r = (T)raw[i];`:

> `Преобразование типа Contact в T невозможно`

При чем если я сделаю iConvert не генериком, заменив везде `T` на `ContactTarget`, то все работает, как надо (вызывается explicit).

**UPDATE:**

Пробовал заменить Contact на object:

```
    static List<T> iConvert<T>(List<object> raw) 
    {
        var res = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Count; i++)
        {
            var r = (T)raw[i];
            res.Add(r);
        }
        return res;
    }    


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new List<object>()
        {
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" }
        };

        // var b = a.Select(i => (Contacts)i).ToList();
        var b = iConvert<ContactTarget>(a);

        b[0].Log();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

В этом случае ошибка на той же строке, но уже в рантайме и выглядит более приятно:

> Не удалось привести тип объекта "ConsoleApplication1.Contact" к типу
>   "ConsoleApplication1.ContactTarget"

Эта ошибка, если не вдаваться в детали, довольно странная. **Поскольку в классе `ContactTarget` явно определен explicit для `Contact`. Но в этом случае он почему-то игнорируется**. Вероятно, причиной состоит в `object` и в необходимости как-то явно преобразовать его в рантайме iConvert() в тип `Contact`, но не могу представить, как это сделать.

PS: пытался еще решить через `var r = (T)Convert.ChangeType(raw[i], typeof(Contact))` , но безуспешно

**UPDATE 2:**

Пробовал так же такой вариант:

```
    static List<TOut> iConvert<TIn, TOut>(List<object> raw)
    {
        var res = new List<TOut>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Count; i++)
        {
            var r = (TOut)(TIn)raw[i];
            res.Add(r);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Но увы

> Преобразование типа "TIn" в "TOut" невозможно

**UPDATE 3:**

Попробовал вариант из ответа @Ulysses:

```
    static List<TOut> iConvert2<TOut, TIn>(List<TIn> raw) where TIn : TOut
    {
        var res = new List<TOut>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Count; i++)
        {
            var r = (TOut)(TIn)raw[i];
            res.Add((TOut)r);
        }
        return res;
    }   

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new List<Contact>()
        {
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc" },
            new Contact { Name="vazc", Number="9" }
        };

        // var b = a.Select(i => (ContactTarget)(Contact)i).ToList();
        var b = iConvert2<ContactTarget, Contact>(a);
        // var b = iConvert<ContactTarget>(a);

        b[0].Log();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Внутри ContactTarget объявлен оператор:

```
    public static implicit operator ContactTarget(Contact contact)
    {
        var _contact = new ContactTarget();
        _contact.Name = contact.Name;
        _contact.Phone = contact.Number;
        _contact.OptionalPhones = Convert.ToBoolean(contact.Numbers) ? string.Join(";", contact.Numbers) : string.Empty;
        _contact.Photo = contact.PhotoUriThumbnail ?? string.Empty;

        return _contact;
    }//*/
```

На выходе получаю ошибку

> Тип "ConsoleApplication1.Contact" не может быть использован как параметр-тип "TIn" в универсальном типе или методе "ConsoleApplication1.Program.iConvert(System.Collections.Generic.List)". Отсутствует неявное преобразование ссылки из "ConsoleApplication1.Contact" в "ConsoleApplication1.ContactTarget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первый вариант _iConvert<T>_ сработал бы, если бы язык и компилятор поддерживали ограничения на приводимость типа для дженериков, наподобие `where T : (T)Contact`, но этого, увы, нет (даже в С#8). Вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919177/193999) ответ посмотрите.

Comment: Вроде бы можно вот так (TOut)(dynamic)(TIn), ну а у себя сделал кастомный метод конвертации через кодогенерацию конвертера, который использует explicit - из explicit компилятор генерит методы с четко заданными именами, я их нахожу и использую

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас я нашел решение, которое меня устроило. Оно, правда говоря, не является ответом на текущий вопрос (связанный с игнорированием explicit/implicit и приведением типов в рантайме), но тем не менее приведенный ниже способ помог решить поставленную задачу.

Я видоизменил метод iConvert следующим образом:

```
    static List<TOut> iConvert<TOut>(List<object> raw) where TOut : IModel, new()
    {
        var res = new List<TOut>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Count; i++)
        {
            var r = new TOut().Create(raw[i]);
            res.Add((TOut)r);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Где `IModel` - это интерфейс, в котором объявлен метод `Create`, а тип `TOut` (`contactTarget`) реализует этот интерфейс.

Вместо оператора приведения использовал конструктор, а метод  `Create` используется для передачи в него аргумента для преобразования. По сути получилась искусственная реализация `explicit`.

Всем спасибо за внимание

P.S Если у кого будут идеи по исходной реализации, буду рад обсудить

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ограничение на приводимость типов:

```
static List<T> iConvert<T,U>(List<U> raw) where U : T
{
    ... //ваш код
}
```

и все заработает.

Comment: Но у меня эти классы не наследованы друг от друга

Comment: В общем я проверил, на всякий случай. `Тип "ConsoleApplication1.Contact" не может быть использован как параметр-тип "TIn" в универсальном типе или методе "ConsoleApplication1.Program.iConvert<TIn,TOut>(System.Collections.Generic.List<TIn>)". Отсутствует неявное преобразование ссылки из "ConsoleApplication1.Contact" в "ConsoleApplication1.ContactTarget"`. В классе ContactTarget `explicit` на `implicit` менял... Не помогло

Comment: Вот поставьте мой заголовок метода вместо своего и увидите, что все работает. На самом деле ограничение `where U : T` означает что тип `U` приводим к типу `T`. Наследование — частный случай.

Comment: вероятно, вы правы. Но почему-то это не сработало для меня (обновил вопрос (см. UPDATE 3 с попыткой реализации вашего решения)

Comment: Был неправ. Все же `where U : T` означает совпадение или (опосредованное) наследование.